# Find time to write a number in one figure

Tags: javascript, time, timer, calculation, milliseconds

write a function to calculate the number of milliseconds needed to type a number with one finger in javaScript

am try to solve this question but i don't have any idea how am solve this problem.

Comment: Time between each character typing ?

Comment: What are you thinking of regarding the UI? Should it be a simple CLI application where you just measure the time from asking the user to type something in until he presses enter or is it a website or some other UI where you start whenever the first character/ digit is entered and end as soon as the last one is entered?

Comment: its just a basic example we just write a function like function fName(pattrenOfNumber, numberWeEnter){  // here we write logic how much time time to write this number}

Comment: example:  Input: digits = "0123456789", num = "201"        Output: 4

Comment: Now I am even more confused :D How long it takes Node/ Browser (?) to write a number to the console in milliseconds? That could potentially be 4 (a user is certainly slower). Or do you want to prompt a user to enter the number and measure how long this takes. I also don't get why you would provide digits as a parameter to the function?

Comment: Independent from what you actually want to measure you can use `const start = Date.now()` to start measuring, then do whatever you need to do and then call `const end = Date.now()` and then calculate the time elapsed in milliseconds using `end - start`.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If I understand the comments well here's the answer

```
 function calcTime (digits, num ){
        const digits_arr = Array.from(digits);
        let last_index = 0, new_index, time =0;
        for (const n of num) {
            new_index =digits_arr.findIndex(x => x===n);
            time += Math.abs(new_index - last_index);
            last_index = new_index;
        }
        return time;
    }
```

example: Input: digits = "0123456789", num = "201" Output: 4

Comment: num = "201" will be num = "210"

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution of Time Complexity: `O(n)`  and Space Complexity: `O(1)`:

```py
def typing_time(digits, num):
    typing_time = 0
    start = 0
    for digit in num:
        index = digits.index(digit)
        typing_time += abs(start - index)
        start = index
    return typing_time

# Test code
print(typing_time('0123456789', '210')) # 4
print(typing_time('8459761203', '5439')) # 17
```

Answer (score -1):

Thanks to [AbdelazizAlsabagh's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71572907) I've finally understand the trick with the indexes!. I'm posting the full problem to solve (untested).

### **Number Generator**

A digit-only keyboard contains all 10 digits from 0 to 9. They all exist in one line.
Give a string of 10 digits illustrating how the keys are positioned. To type a digit, you start from index zero to the index of the target digit. It takes |a - b| milliseconds to move from index a to index b.

Write a function to calculate the number of milliseconds needed to type a number with one finger.

**Input**: digits = '0123456789', num = '210

**Output**: 4

**Input**: digits = '8459761203', num = '5439'

**Output**: 17

Constraints:

- digits.length == 10
- digits contains each digit [0-9] exactly one in some order
- 1 <= num.length <= 10e4
- num[i] is digit

```
def number_gen_idx(digits: str, nums: str) -> str:
    """
    >>> number_gen_idx('0123456789', '210')
    4
    >>> number_gen_idx('8459761203', '5439')
    17
    """
    digits_idx = defaultdict(int)
    for idx, digit in enumerate(digits):
        digits_idx[digit] = idx
    curr_ptr = 0
    result = 0
    for digit in nums:
        result += abs((digits_idx[digit] - curr_ptr))
        curr_ptr = digits_idx[digit]
    return result
```

Comment: That is a brute force solution without checking all constraints. Maybe you could polish guys!